How to connect gns3 simulated network to my physically existed network
I have a VM existing in one network and a c3660 R1 router in a different network within GNS3. I would like to establish connectivity between router R1 and my VM.
The details for the VM and gns3 R1 router are as follows:

VM IP address is 10.200.2.180, subnet mask is 255.255.255.0, gateway is 10.200.2.250, and the network interface is ens160.
The router's IP address is 10.1.2.23, subnet mask is 255.255.255.0, gateway is 10.1.2.0, and the network interface is FastEthernet 0/0.

The routing configuration for R1 is displayed as follows:
R1#show ip route                
C 10.1.2.0 is directly connected to FastEthernet0/0,
C 10.2.2.0 is directly connected to FastEthernet0/1,
and S* 10.200.2.0 [1/0] via 10.1.2.0.

I have added routing on both ends. On the VM with sudo ip route add 10.1.2.0/24 via 10.200.2.1 dev ens160, and on R1 with ip route 10.200.2.0 255.255.255.0 FastEthernet0/1.
However, pinging the router R1's IP address (10.1.2.23) from the VM is not successful, and pinging the VM's IP address (10.200.2.180) from the router R1 is also not successful.
Here is the GNS3 network diagram:


Where would your VM appear on the network diagram? I am unclear on the physical connectivity between the host running your VM and your GNS3 network.

hi @larsks The image is about network created using gns3 components in gns3 webpage, the VM is outside located physically, now is it possible to connect VM and router R1 of GNS3?
